# Inverse of a matrix with binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Let $a(n,k)=(-1)^k {{2n-k}\choose k}$ for $0 \le k \le n$ and $a(n,k)=0$ else. Then it is known (cf. OEIS A005439 and A098435)  that  the first column of the inverse matrix of $(a(i,j))_{i,j\ge0}$  is the sequence $1,1,2,8,56,608,9440,…$ of median Genocchi numbers.

Now let  $b(n,k)=(-1)^k {{2n+1-k}\choose k}$ for $0 \le k \le n$ and $b(n,k)=0$ else.

My question is: Is a formula known for the entries of the first column of the inverse matrix of $(b(i,j))_{i,j\ge0}?$  The first terms of this sequence are $1,  1/2, 1/3, 1/3, 8/15, 4/3, 512/105, 368/15…$. Multiplying the $n-$th term with $n!$ gives the sequence $1,1,2,8,64,960,24576,989184,…$.

**Edit.** Motivated by the comments below and  analogous results by D. Dumont and J. Zeng about Genocchi  numbers  I found the following connections with Bernoulli numbers $B_{2n}.$

1)   Let  $\left( {c(n)} \right)_{n \ge 0}=\left({1,  1/2, 1/3, 1/3, 8/15, 4/3, 512/105, 368/15…}\right).$
Then there is an expansion into a formal power series
$\sum\limits_{n \ge 0} {( - 1)^n c(n)\frac{{z^{2n} }}{{(1 - z)^{n + 1} }}}  = z + \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} {(2n + 1)B_{2n} z^{2n} } .$

2)  ` $c(2n + 1) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {{2n+1}\choose{2j+1}
} (2n + 2j + 3)B_{2n + 2j + 2} $ and $c(2n ) = -\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{n-1} {{2n}\choose{2j+1}
} (2n + 2j + 3)B_{2n + 2j + 2}. $

There remains the question whether the sequence $(c(n))$ also occurs in a natural way in other contexts.

Comment: 1. The `1,1,2,8,64,960...` sequence isn't in the OEIS. 2. Have you tried using the formulae for forward elimination to attempt to derive a series expression for those inverse entries?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try looking at the sequences 1, 1/3, 8/15, 512/105 and 1/2, 1/3, 4/3, 368/15 (the odd- and even-numbered terms of your original sequence). These sequences "look easier" to me in some sense, although I still can't identify them.

Comment: Denote the coefficients of the first columns of $B^-1$ by $c_k$ and the quotient of consecutive coefficients $q_k=c_k/c_{k-1}$ where  $q_0=1 $ .     
Denote the forward differences of 2'nd order as $d_{2,k}$. Then the $d_k$ seem to converge to something like 0.202642045678 .

Comment: @ J.M. I did not quite understand what you mean with forward elimination. But your advice to derive a series expression was helpful.

@ Michael Lugo.  You are right. This becomes easier. See edit of my question.

Comment: @Johann: it's what they call "forward substitution" here: http://books.google.com/books?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=PA88 ; one thing that may ease things is that most of the `$b_i$` (to use the notation of that book) are zero.

Comment: FWIW, `RSolve[{p[i] == Sum[((-1)^(i + j - 1)*Binomial[2*i - j, j - 1]*p[j])/i, {j, 1, i - 1}], p[1] == 1}, p[i], i]` doesn't work in my version of *Mathematica*.

Comment: @ J.M. If I understand you correctly you want to compute the sequence $c(n)$ with Mathematica. This can e.g. be done by setting

 c[n_]:=(Sum[(-1)^(n+j+1)Binomial[2n+1-j,j]c[j],{j,0,n-1}])⁄((n+1));c[0]:=1.

In this way you only get the numerical values but no formula.


Comment: @Johann: `RSolve[]` is supposed to (attempt to) determine an explicit formula from a difference equation. For efficiently computing in *Mathematica* however, one does so-called dynamic programming: `c[n_]:=c[n]=...`